# Best Way to Merge 3 Columns Together to Make Unique Database Column? Trigger?

Tags: sql-server, database, ef-core-2.1

I have a table on items what sort of looks like this.

```
ItemsTbl
id -PK
BrandId- int (FK)
LocationId- int (FK)
Field3 - nvarchar(Max) Json string containing a jsonKey called itemNumber
```

Now I am building an importer(takes in an excel file) that will mass import a 1000 items at a time. But before I can insert them I have to check if they exist in the database.

If so then update, if not new record.

Ideal world, I would either would like the customer to have a field in their excel file of a unique number(through their pk in the db or something else) and store that in my db. If it matches what we have in our db then update otherwise it is new.

I been told by business that is not possible as they think 90% of the customer base will not be able to figure out how to give us a file with a unique column to use as identifier.

I also can't regenerate the file again with unique numbers as I been told most will be pulling the list fresh each time they decide to import.

So the new idea is to have a new column on the database that will combine `BrandId + LocationId + itemNumber` then each time a file comes through join those 3 fields from the excel file and do a check.

I am worried of this field becoming out of sync as if they manually go into our system and change any of those 3 fields that field would have to change.

I guess trigger would be the best to stop this but I am not sure if it is possible to have a trigger on a field that contains json.

I am using EF Core, Sql Server 2017.

The reason why I don't try to do something like this

```
select * from ItemsTbl where BrandId = 1 AND LocationId = 1 And JSON_VALUE('Field3',$.itemNumber) = 12345
```

is because like I said I am getting 1000 items at a time in, I don't want to do a 1000 separate queries. I rather do 1 query with a `in` clause then loop through the results of that and update.

Comment: Why not store all 3 fields but do a MERGE operation rather than separate UPDATE and INSERT?

Comment: Can you show an example of this as I am not sure what you mean. Right now the actual saving/inserting is down by EF Bulk Update?insert

Comment: The answer from Simonare has an example of using a MERGE statement.  Basically it allows a single statement to match all of the incoming data to the existing data in the table and either INSERT or UPDATE depending on whether a match is found.

Comment: Ok, I been looking at still don't get all of it. First thing is the Target.ItemNumber is coming from a json column. So I am not sure how that works. I also got to read about this "Type" and how it works and is this SP inserting/updating 1 record at a time or doing it in batches?

Comment: @Ben - I updated my select statement to show what I mean by being in Json if it was not clear before.

Comment: Given you were already planning to create a field comprising of all 3 fields and using it for comparisons, I assumed that extracting the ItemNumber from the JSON was something you were already planning.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use Standard ADO.NET libraries to do this.

Create a Procedure which get Table Valued Parameter as input, and pass your bulk data inside that parameter. After that you can use `MERGE` function to make both update and insert (UPSERT) operation with one call.

```
/* Create a table type. */  
CREATE TYPE SourceTableType AS TABLE   
( BrandId INT  
, LocationId INT
, ItemNumber INT
, ...
);  
GO 


CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_InsertTvp  
@Source SourceTableType READONLY  
    AS        
    MERGE INTO Table1 AS Target  
    USING @Source As Source 
      ON Target.BrandId = Source.BrandId and
         Target.LocationId = Source.LocationId and
         Target.ItemNumber = Source.ItemNumber  
    WHEN MATCHED THEN  
    UPDATE SET OtherParam = Source.OtherParam  
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN  
    INSERT (BrandId, LocationId, ItemNumber, OtherParam) VALUES (BrandId, LocationId, ItemNumber, OtherParam) ;
```

On the .Net Side you need use

```
using (connection)  
{  
  // Create a DataTable with the modified rows.  
  DataTable myTable = ...;  

  // Define the INSERT-SELECT statement.  
  string sqlInsert = "dbo.usp_InsertTvp"  

  // Configure the command and parameter.  
  SqlCommand mergeCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlInsert, connection);  
  mergeCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  SqlParameter tvpParam = mergeCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Source", myTable);  
  tvpParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;  
  tvpParam.TypeName = "dbo.SourceTableType";  

  // Execute the command.  
  insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();  
}
```

PS: the code is not tested, It may have syntactical problems.

---

Merge Syntax

```
MERGE  [ INTO ] <target_table> [ AS ] table_alias
USING <table_source>   
  ON <merge_search_condition>  
WHEN MATCHED [ AND <clause_search_condition> ]  
    THEN <merge_matched> ] [ ...n ]  
[ WHEN NOT MATCHED [ BY TARGET ] [ AND <clause_search_condition> ]  
    THEN <merge_not_matched> ]
```

where

```
merge_matched>::=  
{ UPDATE SET <set_clause> | DELETE }  

<merge_not_matched>::=  
{  
    INSERT [ ( column_list ) ]   
        { VALUES ( values_list )  
        | DEFAULT VALUES }  
}
```

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#syntax)

Comment: hmm, so I modify all my rows, through my C# code then instead of calling my EF Bulk Update method. I call this SP instead and let it figure out what if to update or insert it? The one thing though is I see you do "Target.ItemNumber = Source.ItemNumber " as I said this is in a Json string, so is this still possible to do? I guessing if it is possible that syntax has to change?

Comment: I also don't get how the SourceTableType gets populated. Can you add comments to each area as it's been a very long time since I used SP and even then it was quite basic.

Comment: for your first question => Yes. Just you need to call this SP. For the second question, I am sure it can be applied to json as well however I don't have experience with it. just one thing, are you going to update whole json or just part of it?

Comment: SourceTableType is populated from ` DataTable myTable`

Comment: ok, maybe have to start a new question on the question about json as that will make or break if I can do this or not. Well parts of it will be updated of the json string but I think I will let the C# rebuild the whole json string and resave it as I guessing that might be just easier. SourceTableType will have all the same parameters as my Table1 then?

Comment: I think it might be as simple as doing  JSON_VALUE(Target.Field3, '$.ItemNumber')  =  JSON_VALUE(Source.Field3, '$.ItemNumber')

Comment: I do have a question about "using" I read that "USING Clause is used to match only one column when more than one column matches." Mine matches all matches that fit the criteria is that the expected behavior?

Comment: using clause is used for deciding which operation is going to be made (update or insert). so If all your rows matched then this query going to update all of your records and no insertion will be made.

Comment: Ah got it, that makes sense. The syntax is for this is bit confusing for me, if you could add comments that would be great. Like '@Source' SourceTableType READONLY  is this "Table Type" or the datacoming? and then later on you  USING '@Source' As Source  not sure what that refers to now. Then witht he Update how does it know to update the real table and not the "Table Type" is it because of Merge Into?

Comment: yep, merge into <target_table> using <source_table>, I will add definition for it

Comment: Stick your excel data into the source table (think of it as a staging table), and then the stored procedure is just standard sql using what's basically a join between the source and taget tables to decide whether to insert or update each row.